# Is it possible to manage windows in batch mode in vanilla dwm?

Tags: dwm

I'd like to be able to execute the following workflow (that is now manual using both keyboard and mouse) by running a script with arguments in console:

1. make currently focused window floating (Mod1-Shift-Space)
2. resize window to given width and height (Mod1-Button3)
3. move it to a given workspace (Mod1-Shift-[1..n]) dwm calls it applying a tag to the window
4. position the window at given coordinates (Mod1-Button1)

I know I could probably do this in some other window manager that has a sophisticated IPC implementation. i3 comes to mind. But I'm really not willing to switch away from dwm. Can I do it in vanilla dwm somehow?

Comment: Not in vanilla, no. And the amount of patching required to achieve this suggests that i3 would be a simpler move.